# Debugging in VS Code fails: The project file could not be loaded (MSB4025)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, .net-core, project.json

I'm trying to debug a NETCore project in VS Code but launching the debugger gives me the following error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. 
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. 

c:\path\to\my\project.json
```

project.json content:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the project.json format is not longer supported. More info here on [GitHub](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1034).